# NanoPB Help! encoding nested repeated items and not sure I have the schema defined properly

Tags: decode, encode, nanopb

I am defining a breakdown for a battery pack.
Packs are made of one or more Modules.
Modules are made of 6 Cells.

I have been able to get the pack information minus the repeated modules. I believe my repeated modules are now encoding but get an error:
`Decoding failed: parent stream too short`

currently my proto looks like this

```cpp
    syntax = "proto2";
    
    package TeslaBMS;
    
    message Pack { 
      required int32 numberOfModules = 2;
      required float currentVoltage = 3;
      required float averagePacktemp = 4;
      repeated Module modules = 5;
    
        message Module {
          required int32 id = 1;
          required float moduleVoltage = 2;
          required float moduleTemp = 3;
          required float lowestCellVolt = 4;
          required float highestCellVolt = 5;
      //   repeated Cell cells = 6;
    
      //  message Cell{
      //       required int32 cellId = 1;
      //       required float cellVolt = 2;
      //       required string balanceState = 3;
      //  }
    
      }
    }
```

Which produces these struct defs

```cpp
/* Struct definitions */
typedef struct _TeslaBMS_Pack {
    int32_t numberOfModules;
    float currentVoltage;
    float averagePacktemp;
    pb_callback_t modules;
} TeslaBMS_Pack;

typedef struct _TeslaBMS_Pack_Module {
    int32_t id;
    float moduleVoltage;
    float moduleTemp;
    float lowestCellVolt;
    float highestCellVolt;
} TeslaBMS_Pack_Module;
```

**I have made a typedef struct to hold an array of modules**

```cpp
typedef struct{
    TeslaBMS_Pack_Module modarr[MAX_MODULE_ADDR];
    int listSize = 0;
}
ModuleList;
```

These are some helper functions to build module arrays
the `modulelist_add_module` is used for decode and `module_array_maker` is used for encode

**Here is what I have for my encode/decode based on examples I could find.**

Encode:

```cpp
void encoder(){
    // Setup pack message
    TeslaBMS_Pack mypack = TeslaBMS_Pack_init_zero;
    
    // stream to write buffer
    pb_ostream_t stream = pb_ostream_from_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    // set deffinitions     
    mypack.averagePacktemp = bms.getAvgTemperature();
    mypack.currentVoltage = bms.getPackVoltage();
    mypack.numberOfModules = bms.getNumOfModules();

    ModuleList modArr;
    module_array_maker(&modArr);

      // set the arg to data needed
    mypack.modules.arg = &modArr;

      // encode the modules
    mypack.modules.funcs.encode = modules_encode;

      //encode the pack
    status = pb_encode(&stream, TeslaBMS_Pack_fields, &mypack);
    message_length = stream.bytes_written;
        
        if (!status) printf("Encoding failed: %s\n", PB_GET_ERROR(&stream));
}
```

**Encode call back for repeated module field**

```cpp
bool modules_encode(pb_ostream_t *stream, const pb_field_iter_t *field, void * const *arg)
{    
    ModuleList *source = (ModuleList*)(*arg);

    for(int i=0; i<bms.getNumOfModules();i++)
    {
        printf(" \n Mod %i is at %f \n",(int)source->modarr[i].id, source->modarr[i].moduleVoltage);
        if (!pb_encode_tag_for_field(stream, field))
        {
            const char * error = PB_GET_ERROR(stream);
            printf("encode_modules error: %s", error);
            return false;
        }
        if (!(stream, TeslaBMS_Pack_Module_fields, &source->modarr[i]))
        {
            const char * error = PB_GET_ERROR(stream);
            printf("SimpleMessage_encode_numbers error: %s", error);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Decode:

```cpp
void decode(){
    /* Allocate space for the decoded message. */
    TeslaBMS_Pack myPack = TeslaBMS_Pack_init_zero;
    
    /* Create a stream that reads from the buffer. */
    
    ModuleList modArr;
    module_array_maker(&modArr);
    myPack.modules.arg = &modArr;
    myPack.modules.funcs.decode = modules_decode;

    pb_istream_t stream = pb_istream_from_buffer(buffer, message_length);
    /* Now we are ready to decode the message. */
    status = pb_decode(&stream, TeslaBMS_Pack_fields, &myPack);
    
    /* Check for errors... */
    if (!status)
    {
        printf("Decoding failed: %s\n", PB_GET_ERROR(&stream));
    }
    else
    {
        /* Print the data contained in the message. */
        printf("\n********MESSAGE FROM NANOPB!*********\n");
        // printf("Number Of Modules in Pack: ", myPack.numberOfModules);
        printf("Pack Voltage: %.3f\n", myPack.currentVoltage);
        printf("Average Temp: %.3f\n", myPack.averagePacktemp);
        printf("Number of modules: %i\n", (int)myPack.numberOfModules);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < myPack.numberOfModules ; i++)
        {
            printf("\n    ************  Module %i  ************\n", modArr.modarr[i].id);
            printf("       Voltage: %.3f Temperature: %.3f \n" ,modArr.modarr[i].moduleVoltage, modArr.modarr[i].moduleTemp);
        }        
        printf("********MESSAGE FROM NANOPB!*********\n");
    }
}
```

**Decode callback for modules**

```cpp
bool modules_decode(pb_istream_t *istream, const pb_field_t *field, void **arg){
    ModuleList * dest = (ModuleList*)(*arg);

    TeslaBMS_Pack_Module module;
    if(!pb_decode(istream, TeslaBMS_Pack_Module_fields, &module)){
        const char * error = PB_GET_ERROR(istream);
        printf("module_decode error: %s", error);
        return false;
    }
    
    modulelist_add_module(dest, module);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you know an upper limit for the number of items in repeated fields, specify `max_count` option and you'll get simple arrays for them: https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/docs/concepts.html#data-types

Comment: That should work well for the cells but the modules will be an unknown number prescribed by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to update this.
Looks like we just needed to make a little more space for the message. We took the max message size we would expect and added a few more bytes to pass into the encoder function and changed the encoder function from: `void encoder()` to:  `size_t encoder(pb_byte_t *buffer, size_t length)`

Setup and calls to encode and decode

```cpp
pb_byte_t buffer[128];

size_t msg_length = encoder(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
decode(buffer, msg_length);
```

Encode function:

```cpp
size_t encoder(pb_byte_t *buffer, size_t length) {
    // Setup pack message
    TeslaBMS_Pack mypack = TeslaBMS_Pack_init_zero;
    // stream to write buffer
    pb_ostream_t stream = pb_ostream_from_buffer(buffer, length);
    // set definitions     
    mypack.averagePacktemp = bms.getAvgTemperature();
    mypack.currentVoltage = bms.getPackVoltage();
    mypack.numberOfModules = bms.getNumOfModules();

    ModuleList modArr;
    module_array_maker(&modArr);
    mypack.modules.arg = &modArr;
    mypack.modules.funcs.encode = modules_encode;
    
    //encode the pack
    bool status = pb_encode(&stream, TeslaBMS_Pack_fields, &mypack);
    if (!status) {
        printf("Encoding failed: %s\n", PB_GET_ERROR(&stream));
    }
    printf("Encoded %d bytes\n", stream.bytes_written);
    return stream.bytes_written;
}
```

Decode Function was changed to accept 2 parameters

```cpp
void decode(pb_byte_t *buffer, size_t message_length){
    /* Allocate space for the decoded message. */
    TeslaBMS_Pack myPack = TeslaBMS_Pack_init_zero;
        
    ModuleList modArr;
    module_array_maker(&modArr);
    myPack.modules.arg = &modArr;
    myPack.modules.funcs.decode = modules_decode;
    
    pb_istream_t stream = pb_istream_from_buffer(buffer, message_length);
    bool status = pb_decode(&stream, TeslaBMS_Pack_fields, &myPack);
    if (!status)
    {
        printf("Decoding failed: %s\n", PB_GET_ERROR(&stream));
        return;
    }
    /* Print the data contained in the message. */
    printf("\n********MESSAGE FROM NANOPB!*********\n");
    // printf("Number Of Modules in Pack: ", myPack.numberOfModules);
    printf("Pack Voltage: %.3f\n", myPack.currentVoltage);
    printf("Average Temp: %.3f\n", myPack.averagePacktemp);
    printf("Number of modules: %i\n", (int)myPack.numberOfModules);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < myPack.numberOfModules ; i++)
    {
        printf("\n    ************  Module %i  ************\n", modArr.modarr[i].id);
        printf("       Voltage: %.3f Temperature: %.3f \n" ,modArr.modarr[i].moduleVoltage, modArr.modarr[i].moduleTemp);
    }        
    printf("********MESSAGE FROM NANOPB!*********\n");
}
```